# MySQL - Create Search On custom Column

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I want to run a MySQL query like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM `project` WHERE (project.sold_tons + project.recycled_tons + project.recycled_tons + project.donation_tons)*100/project.total_excess_furniture)>90
```

When I run it, I am getting an error like this:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near ')>90 ORDER BY `is_archived` DESC 
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

Can I do it?
Or,
Is there any alternative solution to create a search like this?

If not, then what is the solution in Laravel or MySQL?

Thanks for helping..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you miss '(' after where

try this

```
SELECT * FROM `project` 
WHERE ((project.sold_tons + project.recycled_tons + project.recycled_tons + project.donation_tons) *100/project.total_excess_furniture) > 90
```

Answer (score 0):

project.total_excess_furniture) <--   This scope is extra